# Receiving an error while moving the files via Execute shell in Jenkin

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I have setup the Jenkin in Ubuntu 20.04 and integrated it with GIThub. GIThub is working fine with Jenkin. What I want to do is when build execute successfully, the files should be moved from Jenkin server to Remote server which is hosted on AWS.

I am moving the file through Execute shell. I am receiving the following error.

```
20:30:35 Started by user administrator
20:30:35 Running as SYSTEM
20:30:35 Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/axxxxxxg.co.uk
20:30:35 The recommended git tool is: NONE
20:30:35 No credentials specified
20:30:35  > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/axxxxxg.co.uk/.git # timeout=10
20:30:35 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
20:30:35  > git config remote.origin.url https://ghp_TGxxxxxxxxxxxxr8@github.com/sxxxxxxxg/acxxxxxxg.co.uk.git # timeout=10
20:30:35 Fetching upstream changes from https://ghp_TGxxxxxxxxxxxxxr8@github.com/stxxxxxxg/acxxxxxxg.co.uk.git
20:30:35  > git --version # timeout=10
20:30:35  > git --version # 'git version 2.25.1'
20:30:35  > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://ghp_Txxxxxxxxxxxxtr8@github.com/sxxxxxxg/axxxxxxg.co.uk.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
20:30:35  > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/main^{commit} # timeout=10
20:30:35 Checking out Revision 58fac7a25a9a0c32abf620d521888f517eec76ac (refs/remotes/origin/main)
20:30:35  > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
20:30:35  > git checkout -f 58fac7a25a9a0c32abf620d521888f517eec76ac # timeout=10
20:30:35 Commit message: "first commit"
20:30:35  > git rev-list --no-walk 58fac7a25a9a0c32abf620d521888f517eec76ac # timeout=10
20:30:35 [acxxxxxxg.co.uk] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins10370085014864703303.sh
20:30:35 + /home/accxxxxk.sh
20:30:36 Host key verification failed.
20:30:36 rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
20:30:36 rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.3]
20:30:36 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
20:30:36 Finished: FAILURE
```

I will be happy if anyone help to out.

- I have checked the permission of the authorized_keys file on the remote server and it is 600. I have re-created the private and public but didn't get success. Also, I am able to execute the same script from the terminal in Jenken server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with your `ssh` connection between `Jenkins` `server` and your `remote` server, you can try these things:

1. first check `ssh`, check that the connection settings are correct (ip address, port number, username, private key path).
2. check the configuration your remote server, the `sshd_config` file, and make sure that `AllowUsers` and `AllowGroups` include the `Jenkins` user.
3. Be sure that the private key file that `Jenkins` is using has the correct permission it should be `-rw-------` and owned by the `Jenkins` user.

You can also test the `ssh` conection manually, check the firewall, the `ssh` Agent settings, Hope it help